# Is there a way in Unity to track a keyboard keystroke without using Update()?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to optimize my game and I have a question. Is it possible to track keystrokes in Unity without Update()? Although I don’t have many functions in it, is it still possible to optimize it somehow? Is it better to read keys in FixedUpdate()?

I would appreciate any advice on optimization

Answer (score 0):

This is probably gonna be the least of your worries, but you can move all keystrokes to one Update and event it out on your own. Otherwise, the new [InputSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.5/manual/Workflows.html) does allow for events (at least on your side, because on their own it's most likely an Update like situation anyhow), but you'll have to define actions instead of keystrokes (e.g. Jump instead of is-spacebar-pressed).

FixedUpdate is for physics related stuff mostly and I've heard it can lead to precision loss if you do input stuff in there. Also if you want to think optimization, FixedUpdate gets called more than once within a frame, depending on the interval (I think it's something like 0.02s), while Update gets called once. Look into Order of Execution for these functions and their frequency for more information.

My advice is, don't bother unless the action-based workflow is sth you're interested in for other reasons, at this point. If you really want to see what you need to optimize, do a profile, test things, gather profile reports and then optimize whatever is problematic (even if that is the input, which I doubt).